# Why doesn't my query use any index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Here is my query:

```
select u.*,
       concat(user_fname, ' ', user_lname) like concat(?, '%') `both`,
       user_lname like ? last_name
from users u 
where concat(user_fname, ' ', user_lname) like concat(?, '%')
   or user_lname like concat(?, '%')
order by `both`*2 DESC, last_name
```

Also I've two indexes: `users(user_fname,user_lname)`, `users(user_lname)`.

And here is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | u     | ALL  | user_lname    | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9    |  Using where
```

See? It doesn't use any index. Why? and how can I make the query optimal?

Comment: You are using the result of a function.  The indexes (if you have them) are based on the column values not the result of a function.

Comment: this `concat(user_fname, ' ', user_lname) like concat(?, '%')`

Comment: To learn more about index check:  MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) also this website http://use-the-index-luke.com/ and this video.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU&index=53&list=WL

Answer (score 2):

- Don't hide an indexed column inside a function call (`CONCAT`),
- OR is deadly for optimization,
- A leading wildcard (`%`) makes the index unusable in `LIKE`,
- Since you are fetching all the columns, it is impractical to have a "covering" index.
- In some situations, an index for the `ORDER BY` can be used *instead* of for `WHERE`.  But you have a mixture of ASC and DESC, so this is not possible (until version 8.0).

Plan A:  Use a FULLTEXT and MATCH on the the fields.  (There are limitations to FULLTEXT that may make this unusable.)

Plan B:  Have an extra column with the concatenation of the columns and do a single LIKE against it.  (This does not fix all the problems.)

Bottom line:  Indexes are very efficient *if* you live within their constraints.  Your query violates so many of the limitations, that I don't think there is any hope for the query; it must perform a table scan.

Caveat:  There may be more issues.